# Using multiple machine learning algorithms together

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, svm, backpropagation

I'm kinda new to machine learning and wanted to know if we could use multiple machine learning algorithms, for example, SVM and backpropagation together to solve a particular problem.

Comment: yes u can..ex: .i have done random forest for regression problem and again i applied linear regression for the output...the same way based on u r problem u can do

Answer (score 1):

You can train multiple machine learning models with same data and based on accuracy and confusion_matrix response you can decide which one to use.

In theory, you don't need to combine/merge two different ML Models (you can enhance your pre-processing) 
**but if you still want to use different models there are two approaches:**

1. **Ensemble** (available with three categories - a) Bagging b) Boosting c) Stacking
2. **Hybrid** (This approach allow users to create own models (or use existing) and combine them for better prediction)

Note: You need to be careful with individual algorithm response before combining them together :)

Answer (score 0):

In a classification/regression task you can use back propagation and SVM:

- Backpropagation: use a neural network as feature extractor
- SVM: use it to perform classification/regression with the features extracted with the neural network

In deed, in neural networks back-propagation and other well-known machine learning techniques are used together. For example, when a *sigmoid* layer is used as the classification layer for a binary classification neural net, a logistic regression is performed and optimized through back-propagation